# Intellij auto-generate java method at the end of the file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any way to ask the auto-generate methods created by intellij to be generated at the end of the class?
currently when i generate a method (⌥⌘M) it is created right below the function I extracted the method from, and I would like it to be at the end of the file.
Does intellij offer that option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-arrange the code in IntelliJ after code generation manually even though this does not guarantee that the code will go to the bottom of the file. You can do that by clicking on the "Rearrange" menu item in the "Code" menu:

[image]

Another option to re-arrange the code without having to use the menus would be via the "Reformat" file dialogue, by pressing on Windows *Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L* and by activating in it the "Re-format code" checkbox.

[image]

You can change the pattern of code arrangement in the settings in the following dialogue:

[image]

Comment: Great, after adding the desired rules for the arrangement, and rearranging the file I've managed do get the desired output.

Comment: @DsCpp What rule did you add?

Answer (score 0):

> There is no such option in Intellij, Once you extract method you can move method up and down using Press **Up( ⌥ ⇧ Up) or Down( ⌥ ⇧ Down)**.

Comment: so the default and only option is right beneath the place you extracted from?

Comment: @DsCpp yes by default that is the only option